# Getting information of a model from another model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

My project is simply a patient will upload an image of his latest medical report that includes blood pressure , hemoglobin and so on , the data will be extracted from the image using ocr . later these data should be shown in a dashboard

This is the model for the image upload:

**models.py**

```
class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    imageTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    image  = models.ImageField(upload_to=media , max_length=100)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

and this is the model that will be created as an instance of the last model created:

```
class ImageData(model.Model):
    haemoglobin = models.FloatField()
    bloodPressure  = models.FloatField()
    mch  = models.FloatField()
```

where haemoglobin , bloodPressure , mch are the data to be extracted .

So I have two questions: 
1) how can I create an instance of ImageData model as an instance of ImageUpload is created ? 
2) I have already a function for the ocr , I tested it manually , however I want to know what is
the best way to put this function within this code , for example is it better to make
this function a method in the ImageUpload class ?
for example:-

```
        class ImageUpload(models.Model):
              ---------
              def get_Image_data(image):#using ocr
                  ---------
                  return text
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override `ImageUpload.save`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    created = self.id is None
    if created:
        (create ImageData object)
    save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mohammad Diab - You can use signals. post_save signal precisely and wire it to your ImageUpload.In the post_save handler you can do something like this
Also, you should use a foreignkey or onetoone field based on your usecase in your ImageData

```
 class ImageData(model.Model):
        image_upload = models.ForeignKey(ImageUpload,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        haemoglobin = models.FloatField()
        bloodPressure  = models.FloatField()
        mch  = models.FloatField()
```

signals.py

```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from .models import ImageData,ImageUpload
    from django.dispatch import receiver

   @receiver(post_save, sender=ImageUpload)
   def save_image_data(sender, instance, **kwargs):
         #write your logic here

post_save.connect(save_image_data, sender=ImageUpload)
```

Comment: a ForeignKey or OneToOnefield ?

Comment: @MohammadDiab- You can use either. I would use a ForeignKey